# Generics cannot find symbol

Tags: java, generics, bounded-types

I have a class defined as follows:

```
static class ParallelMergeSort<T extends Comparable<Pair>> extends RecursiveAction
```

Where `Pair` is a class defined above with a method `getSecond()`.

In the merge sort class, I have a method defined as:

```
  private boolean isLess(T a, T b) {
  if (a instanceof Pair<?,?>) return a.getSecond().compareTo(b.getSecond()) < 0;
  return a.compareTo(b) < 0;
  }
```

Even though I am checking that `T` will be an instance of `Pair` the compiler still comes up with the error `cannot find symbol`:

```
return a.getSecond().compareTo(b.getSecond()) < 0;
                                ^
```

What should I change to alleviate this issue?

Comment: @downvoters Mind leaving a comment as to what is wrong with the question? I'm just curious

Comment: Does the caret really point to `getSecond` of `b`?

Comment: @mkl no sorry my bad, it added an extra space when i pasted it in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do the check:

```
if (a instanceof Pair)
```

then you should cast `a` and `b` to `Pair` and then do the comparison:

```
if (a instanceof Pair && b instanceof Pair) {
    Pair<?, ?> cast_a = (Pair) a;
    Pair<?, ?> cast_b = (Pair) b;
    return cast_a.getSecond().compareTo(cast_b.getSecond()) < 0;
}
```

Currently, the compiler fails to compile, because `T` could be potentially another sub-type of `Comparable<Pair>`, and since the compiler doesn't have any evidence that `T` will be exactly `Pair` then it disallows compilation.

Few notes on your code:

- the right operand of the `instanceof` operator should be just raw. Being generic (as `Pair<?, ?>`) doesn't make any sense, because this check will be done at Runtime, when the generic information will be erased.
- I'm not sure if you design is good, so you should re-consider it, at the least. Having to use `instanceof` is a sign for bad design.

Comment: Thanks, i forgot about erasure in java when writing that. Also yes this is quite a sketchy design, i could overload the function and get rid of the generics however this would result in over 4 copies of the same function.